# File Transfer using TCP and python

Tags: python, networking, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient

I am trying to make a server that can connect many clients to it and the clients can send and receive messages and files, the server is always open. The messages are sent and received perfectly and the files are also sent the problem comes when the file is sent completely, the sender program sends a string "finished" to declare that the file is sent successfully and now they can start sending normal messages. But the server does not accept the string. Instead, the sender has to type the string "finished" and then the messages will be sent to the receiver.

This is the server code

```
import socket
from _thread import *
import threading
import select
clients={}

def thread1(c):
    wait=c.fileno()
    select.select([],[wait],[])
    c.send("Enter Your Username:".encode())
    select.select([wait],[],[])
    username=c.recv(4096).decode()
    clients[username]=c
    while True:
        select.select([wait],[],[])
        d=c.recv(4096).decode()
        if d in clients.keys():
            s=clients[d]
            wait2=s.fileno()
            select.select([],[wait],[])
            c.send(("Connected to Username "+d).encode())
            while True:
                select.select([wait],[],[])
                d=c.recv(4096)
                if(d.decode()=="Disconnect1"):
                    break
                elif(d.decode()=="Disconnect"):
                    select.select([],[wait],[])
                    c.send("Disconnect".encode())
                    del clients[username]
                    c.close()
                    print(username+"Disconnected")
                    print("Connections = ", threading.active_count()-2)
                    return
                elif(d.decode()=="File"):
                    select.select([],[wait],[])
                    c.send("fileok".encode())
                    select.select([],[wait2],[])
                    s.send(d)
                    select.select([wait],[],[])
                    d=c.recv(4096)
                    select.select([],[wait2],[])
                    s.send(d)
                    while True:
                        select.select([wait],[],[])
                        d=c.recv(4096)
                        try:
                            if(d.decode()=="finished"):
                                s.send(d)
                                print("done")
                                break
                        except UnicodeDecodeError:
                            pass
                        select.select([],[wait2],[])
                        s.send(d)
                else:
                    select.select([],[wait2],[])
                    s.send(d)
        elif(d=="Disconnect"):
            select.select([],[wait],[])
            c.send("Disconnect".encode())
            del clients[username]
            c.close()
            print(username+" Disconnected")
            print("Connections = ", threading.active_count()-2)
            return
        elif(d=="File"):
            select.select([],[wait],[])
            c.send("Please connect to user first!".encode())
        else:    
            select.select([],[wait],[])
            c.send('Invalid Username'.encode())
        
        
def Main():
    try:
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print("Socket Created succesfully")
    except socket.error as err:
        print("Socket creation failed %s" %(err))
    port=12345
    s.bind(('',port))
    print("socket binded to %s"%(port))
    s.listen()
    print("Socket is listening")
    while True:
        select.select([s.fileno()],[],[])
        c,addr=s.accept()
        print ('Got connection from', addr )
        th=threading.Thread(target=thread1, args=(c,))
        th.start()
        print("Connections = ", threading.active_count()-1)

Main()
```

This is the Client code

```
import socket
import threading
import sys
from tkinter import Tk 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import select
Tk().withdraw()
conn=False
global filesend
filesend = False

def readMessages(skt) :
    while True:
        select.select([skt.fileno()],[],[])   
        msg = skt.recv(4096).decode('latin-1')
        if(msg=='Disconnect'):
            conn=True
            return
        elif(msg=="File"):
            select.select([skt.fileno()],[],[])   
            msg = skt.recv(4096).decode('latin-1')
            f=open(msg,"wb")
            while True:
                select.select([skt.fileno()],[],[])
                msg = skt.recv(4096)
                try:
                    if(msg.decode()=="finished"):
                        print("done")
                        break
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    pass
                f.write(msg)
            f.close()
        elif(msg=="fileok"):
            filesend=True
        else:
            print(f"\nReceived: {msg}")


def sendMessages(skt):
    while True:
        p=input()
        select.select([],[skt.fileno()],[])
        skt.send(p.encode())
        select.select([],[skt.fileno()],[])
        if(p=="File"):
            filesend = True
            if filesend==False:
                print("Not connected to user")
                continue
            filename = askopenfilename()
            f=filename.split("/")
            select.select([],[skt.fileno()],[])
            skt.send(f[-1].encode())
            f=open(filename,"rb")
            while True:
                p=f.read(4096)
                if not p:
                    p="finished"
                    select.select([],[skt.fileno()],[])
                    skt.send(p.encode())
                    print("done")
                    filesend=False
                    break
                select.select([],[skt.fileno()],[])
                skt.send(p)
        if(p=='Disconnect'):           
            return
    
    
PORT = 12345
skt = socket.socket()
skt.connect(('127.0.0.1', PORT))
x=threading.Thread(target=readMessages, args=(skt,))
x.start()
sendMessages(skt)
if(conn):
    skt.close()
```

This is the output when I send a file [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp9yj.png)

Now I have to type "finished" from the sender side if want to continue sending messages from the sender side.
[Output after typing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOm9R.png)

what am I missing?

Comment: This code with lots of select with a single socket followed by a recv on this socket looks very strange to me and it is not really clear what you are trying to do. But it looks like you expect message semantics from TCP - which TCP does not provide. This specifically means that you assume that `send` is guaranteed to send the full data and that there is a 1:1 relationship between `send`  and `recv`  - both assumptions are false.

Comment: you're essentially reinventing a HTTP like protocol.  Just use HTTP and all this lower level stuff will be handled by the robust, mature libraries for HTTP server / client.